# counter using VHSIC Hardware Description Language

Tags: vhdl, counter

The counter must be programmed to a pushbutton to count every time that specific pushbutton is
pushed. Specifically, if the pushbutton is held, the counter must not increase. It must only increase
by one when the pushbutton is released and pushed in again.
There must be three separate counters implemented. Three different dipswitches must select the
specific counter and the FPGA must remember each count. A separate switch must be used to reset
the counter. Only one reset switch may be used for all three counters.

Comment: What is the question? What have you done so far?

Comment: This is the whole question I was given. I have been working on it for days and for now I have been able to make a normal timer/stopwatch instead of a counter as per requirements in the question.

Comment: What is your problem with your code? this appears to be a homework question: https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/9-timer-using-vhdl-practical-student-must-design-implement-timer-using-vhdl-logic-must-ana-q85346733

Comment: Yes it is an assignment and I need to understand before exams

Answer (score 0):

In order to count when the push button is pressed you can make a flag and an input variable to read the current state of the push button. if the variable of the current state is '1' you would go and check the flag if it is false you would increment the counter and change the flag to true. Otherwise if the flag is true this means that the button is still pressed so you will do nothing. if current state of the button returns to '0' this means that the button is not pressed so you change the flag to false.